# What config setting have a selected to display this text at top of page

Tags: magento-1.8

I have just migrated a very problematic site which has some major redirect issues, to try to fix this I have been changing all the settings within the config area and have managed to select one that has started to display some text at the top of every page. The text is along the lines of store view then some text so in this example it says 'Norwegian store view head text'

[image]

Does anyone know what Ive selected or how to get rid of this text?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive the best solution in this case is not to guess, but to search :)

1) Go to MySQL and run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE value LIKE "%store view head%";
```

2) Go to the root folder of your website with SSH and run the following command:

```
grep -R "store view head" *
```

The first will search for this text contained somewhere in system settings. And the second will search across all the Magento files.